# Manually updating jquery ui sortable elements

Tags: jquery-ui, sorting, knockout.js, jquery-ui-sortable

**Scenario:**
Sorting elements in knockout/jquery sortable ui

I use the following event when item is received in the sortable:

```
beforeStop: function (event2, ui2) {
   draggedItem2 = ui2.item;
   itemDroppedIndex2 = ui2.item.index();

   if (fieldInSortable) {
       // change order of the item
       var startPos = $(this).data('start_position');

       // Update order
       ko.contextFor(this).$data.updateElementPriorities(startPos, itemDroppedIndex2);
   } else {
       fieldInSortable = false;
   }
},
```

The `updateElementPriorities` is as follows:

```
self.updateElementPriorities = function (oldIndex, newIndex) {
var fieldUpdated = null;

for (var j = 0; j < self.elementTypes().length; j++) {
    var eType = self.elementTypes()[j];
    var currPriority = eType.priority();

    if (currPriority == oldIndex && !fieldUpdated) {
        eType.priority(newIndex);
        fieldUpdated = eType;
    }

    else if (newIndex < oldIndex) {
        if (currPriority >= newIndex)
            eType.priority(currPriority + 1);
    }

    else if (newIndex > oldIndex) {
        if (currPriority <= newIndex)
            eType.priority(currPriority - 1);
    }
  }

};
```

I use following code to get the sorted items based on priority():

```
var sorted = elementTypes.sort(function (l, r) {
    return l.priority() > r.priority() ? 1 : -1;
});
return sorted;
```

**Problem:**

When adding new elements or when sorting the current elements, usually they dont get sorted the way it should be. Sometimes, I mean sometimes, it shows the correct priority() number but the order is not correct in UI. Is there any other algo; more efficient to do this sorting manually and display the get the correct sorted elements?

*I am in a stage where I can not use any libraries or make major changes which would be a risk to do so. So I would like any suggestion/change in the same code structure please*

**Update:** Some of the priority() properties start getting negative values when I do a lot of dragging around, not yet added any new item. Just by sorting existing items in the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would follow [this](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/dragging-dropping-and-sorting-with.html) paradigm for binding your vm to your sortable dom elements. Then you can just focus on ordering your observable array

Comment: I knew this from before, but I didn't know that it was so easy to use as well. I had taken time to integrate this and works like a charm now in fact much better than I originally created sortable manually. Thanks !